# Flutter create Dropdown Search Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I am looking for a Flutter Plugin to use in one of my POC projects. Idea is to create a dropdown field with a search option, something similar to what you can see on Yatra(dot)com.

It will be really helpful if someone can guide me to create a widget by myself to achieve this.

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this [site](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search) and try out this code

```
Container(
              child: DropdownSearch<String>(
                mode: Mode.DIALOG,
                showSearchBox: true,
                searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
                showAsSuffixIcons: true,
                showClearButton: false,
                dropdownButtonBuilder: (_) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                    size: 24,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                showSelectedItem: true,
                items: ["bs", "test", "company"],
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    // dropDownValue = newValue;
                  });
                },
                // selectedItem: dropDownValue,
              ),
            ),
```